# How to use reduce to iterate an array

Tags: javascript

I have been doing research on the benefits of using reduce over map. Mainly the benefit is that reduce has better performance time.

My question is how would i be able to use reduce to iterate over an array as if i would for the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) function ?

An example

The following code combines the fruits to one string. How would i be able to iterate over this array using the reduce function ?

```
const fruits = ['pears', 'plums', 'grapes', 'apples']

console.log(fruits.reduce( (acc, fruit) => acc.concat(fruit)))

// "pearsplumsgrapesapples"
```

Comment: You are iterating over it with the `reduce` function.

Comment: but how would i map it. like line by line outputting the items in the array.

Comment: The difference is that `.map` always returns an array that has the same length as the original array which means that this two function are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reduce function **indeed** iterates over the array, because it's meant to reduce all the array items to a single value by applying a function.

The map function iterates on the array too, in order to project the array elements to a value calculated by applying a provided function.

The difference between the two functions is that they are iterating over the array for a different purpose. Reduce is used to compute single value, map is used to project each array item to a new value.

In both cases **you can't say anything about the computational complexity** because you are passing a callback and you don't know what that callback is going to do. So the computational complexity depends on the callback function.

Answer (score 3):

You'll sacrifice code legibility for a millisecond of difference but here it is:

```
['pears', 'plums', 'grapes', 'apples'].reduce(function (acc, currentFruit) {
    // Your code here
    acc.push(currentFruit);
    return acc;
 }, []);
```

You'll have to push your current value to a an array because the `reduce` method objective is to reduce the provided data to a single value.

At the end of the day, map is just better, simpler and you won't be able to notice the time difference.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this paper about reduce: https://hackernoon.com/javascript-array-reduce-50403c421968

Comment: will take a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass an empty array as the reduce function accumulators initial value, then within the body of your reduce function you can append to the `acc` which will now be an array and execute conditional logic.

Answer (score 1):

`map` is simple. It calls the function on each element of the input array, and returns a new array containing the corresponding function results.

```
result = array.map(f)
```

is equivalent to

```
result = [f(array[0], 0, array), f(array[1], 1, array), f(array[2], 2, array), ...]
```

You use `reduce` if you want to combine the results of each iteration in a custom way, to produce one result. The function takes two arguments -- the first is the return value of the previous iteration, and the second is the current element from the iteration.

```
result = array.reduce(f, init)
```

is equivalent to

```
temp1 = f(init, array[0], 0, array);
temp2 = f(temp1, array[1], 1, array);
temp3 = f(temp2, array[2], 2, array);
...
result = f(tempN, array[N], N, array);
```

If you don't provide an initial value argument, the first line becomes

```
temp1 = array[0];
```

and the rest is the same.

If you don't actually need a new result, you just want to execute some code on each array element, you use `forEach()`. It's like `map`, but it doesn't collect the results. If you want to log each array element on a new line, you would do:

```
array.forEach(el => console.log(el));
```